# Duplicate componentDidMount logic with useEffect() to load external JavaScript on client side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I’m implementing a rich text editor into a NextJS project. There are no React components for it, and it runs only on the client side, so I have to load the JavaScript and CSS files from an external source and work around SSR. Please don't recommend to use another tool, as that is not an option.

The tool works fine as a class component, but I’d like to port it into a functional component. When I test the functional component, it works occasionally — namely, after I change my file and save (even if it's just adding a space). But as soon as I refresh the page, I lose the editor. I thought it was because the component hadn’t mounted, but now I check for that, yet the issue persists.

I’ve tried various approaches, including Next’s Dynamic import with SSR disabled, but so far only the class method below has worked (the editor works by binding to the `<textarea>` element):

```
import React from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";


class Page extends React.Component {
  state = { isServer: true };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.MyEditor = require("../public/static/cool-editor.js");
    this.setState({ isServer: false }); // Trigger rerender.

    var app = MyEditor("entry"); // Create instance of editr.
  }

  render(props) {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <textarea id="entry"></textarea>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}
export default Page;
```

Last attempt at functional component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";

function hasWindow() {
  const [isWindow, setIsWindow] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setIsWindow(true);
    return () => setIsWindow(false);
  }, []);

  return isWindow;
}

const Editor = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src =
      "http://localhost:3000/static/article-editor/cool-editor.js";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);

  var app = MyEditor("entry");

  return (
    <Layout>
      <textarea id="entry"></textarea>
    </Layout>
  );
};

const Page = () => {
  const isWindow = hasWindow();

  if (isWindow) return <Editor />;

  return null;
};
export default Page;
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useRef` hook in `<textarea>` tag:

```
const refContainer = useRef(null);

return <textarea ref={refContainer}>
```

then `useEffect` to check if the the element has been mounted.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (refContainer.current) {
      refContainer.current.innerHTML = "ref has been mounted";
      console.log("hello");
    }
  }, []);
```

Check the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-dubinsky-7r3oz

Answer (score 0):

Some of the things I could suggest changing:

- `var app = MyEditor("entry");` is being created on every render. Consider using `useRef` as a way to keep instance variable: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables
- In `Editor`, the `MyEditor` variable is not defined.
- `hasWindow` includes a `useEffect` that runs once (with empty dependency array), I don't think it needs the clean up function. To check staying at browser or server, you could simply use  `const isServer = type of window === 'undefined'`
- Custom hook should be named with prefix `use`